# .net core console application throws System.ExecutionEngineException

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I have absolutely no idea what's going on. I create a new project of type `.net core` console application, hit run and get that exception:

> System.ExecutionEngineException
>
> Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing
>   that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. only native
>   runtime code is executing).

It's quite a while ago when I last ran a `.net core` project on this machine.

More Information:

It happens only in visual studio. If I run the console via `cmd` everything works fine. Any idea how to find out what is causing this? I suspect maybe a visual studio extension like Roslynator is causing this exception.

Answer (score 0):

After repairing Visual Studio everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

I was using .net core 2.2 on visual studio 2017 when i had this error. 
So I tried .net core 3.0 on visual studio 2019 preview..... 
voila, it worked... can't explain it, i guess .net core is constantly improving to support legacy code